# Cocos2d: Create Sprite without content

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have to draw some primitives within a cocos2d app. To encapsulate the drawing, I created a custom CCSprite where I am overwriting the `draw` method.

```
@implementation EnergyBar

-(id) init {
    if(self=[super init]){
        [self setAnchorPoint:ccp(0,0)];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) draw
{
    [super draw];

    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glColor4ub(80, 80, 80, ENERGY_ALPHA);
    glLineWidth(1);




    CGPoint vertices2[] = { ccp(0,0),
        ccp(ENERGY_WIDTH,0),
        ccp(ENERGY_WIDTH,ENERGY_HEIGHT),
        ccp(0,ENERGY_HEIGHT)
    };
    ccDrawPoly(vertices2, 4, YES);

}
```

The node draws the rectangle as expected. As soon as I am trying to add this node as a child of `CCSpriteBatchNode` I get a exception `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'CCSprite is not using the same texture id'`.
Within this node I don't want to use any of the tiles defined in the parent's sprite map. So how to add this node as child of `CCSpriteBatchNode` circumventing this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it :)

The goal of `CCSpriteBatchNode` is that parent draws all the children in batch call (so your `draw` will not be called). You need to add the sprite to another parent (not `CCSpriteBatchNode`).

Comment: The batch node is responsible for drawing the object which the energy bar is related to. In a logical manner it doesn't make sense to me to separate those two objects just because cocos2d expects the child to draw a sprite. Is there really no way of doing this? (e.g. manually setting some kind of property which is checked for determining if this exception is thrown?

Comment: There's no reason you can't add your batch node and custom node as children of an empty CCNode at position X,Y and retain some part of your encapsulation. You just simply can't draw stuff that isn't part of a batch, in a batch draw operation.